# Building a high-powered bluetooth speaker, need input on components

Tags: speakers, diy

I'm trying to build a high powered Bluetooth speaker that would be comparable or better in volume and response range than the Brookstone Big Blue Party speaker. Would two of these:

http://www.parts-express.com/goldwood-gw-4028-s-4-woofer-shielded--290-373

and one or two of these:

http://www.parts-express.com/goldwood-gt-322-1-titanium-dome-tweeter-3-3-4-square--270-150

Do much for me, or what instead should I be looking at.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Specs on the Brookstone Big Blue Party speaker:

4 speaker drivers, subwoofer and passive radiator

Power: 72 watts (18 watts per channel, 36-watt sub)

Frequency response: 40Hz-20kHz

Dimensions: 6.3"w x 6.3"d x 15.8"h

The frequency range of the the speakers you linked go down to 70HZ and up to 20kHZ, The Brookstones go down to 40hz, I do not know if the 30hz is enough for the human ear to distinguish much difference, But The human ear can supposedly hear 20 Hz to 20,000 Hz You may want to throw a sub woofer into the mix to get the deep low end.